# Sending a parameter with post and get to an SQL server

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I'm trying to pass a string(fullname) as a paramter however I am constantly redirected back to the users profile(in other words, it fails to give any data for the specific name).
I tried using alert messages to see if the parameter is sent successfully
and the message was blank, so I think it's safe to say the parameter didnt even make it through the pages.

I have been trying to figure out the problem for hours and I gave up, can anyone gimme a direction please?
Here are the codes:
Thiis is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="search"><input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Firstname_Lastname"/><input type="submit" value="Search"/></form>
```

There's another way to access search.php and it is from the list of users via get, but it doesnt work either. When I try to use the user list it just doesnt load up the page. There are no MySQL syntax errors aswell. Here is the search page:

```
<?php
    $title = "Public Profile";
    include 'header.php';
    include 'profiletabs.php';
    checkForLogin();
    if(isset($_GET['uid']) && !is_numeric($_GET['uid']))
    {
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=publicprofile">';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['uid']))
    {
        $query = $_GET['uid']; 
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $resultSearch = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `SQLID` = $query LIMIT 1;");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $_POST['name']; 
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nameri');</script>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(". $_POST['name'].");</script>";
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $resultSearch = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `PlayerName` = '$query' LIMIT 1;");
        $nameri = $query;
                $message = "wrong answer";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nameri');</script>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($nameri);</script>";
    }
    if($resultSearch->rowCount() > 0)         
    {
// Code goes here
    }

else echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=publicprofile">';
```

I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks!

Comment: why you closed extra ' } '   before else..at the last line.i didn't find any open bracket for that one in your code..

Comment: @user3663 Yeah its because I removed some non related code parts so I forgot to remove this one too before posting, anyway thats not the cause.

Comment: did you  enable error reporting..

Answer (score 0):

There some issue with you syntax i have update that hope this will help.
There is not variable with name --> $nameri

```
<?php
    $title = "Public Profile";
    include 'header.php';
    include 'profiletabs.php';
    checkForLogin();
    if(isset($_GET['uid']) && !is_numeric($_GET['uid']))
    {
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=publicprofile">';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['uid']))
    {
        $query = $_GET['uid']; 
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $resultSearch = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `SQLID` = $query LIMIT 1;");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $_POST['name']; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('". $_POST['name']."');</script>";
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        $resultSearch = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `playerinfo` WHERE `PlayerName` = '$query' LIMIT 1;");
        $nameri = $query;
                $message = "wrong answer";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

    }
    if($resultSearch->rowCount() > 0)         
    {
// Code goes here
    }

else echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=publicprofile">';
```

Comment: What did you change? I cant see the difference.

Comment: there is no variable with this name $nameri